# Why Luhn algorithm multiply by 2?

Tags: algorithm, checksum, credit-card, luhn, error-detection

I have question about Luhn algorithm. The luhn algorithm (mod 10) for error detection and check sum digits. For example digits like visa, credit card etc.

for example we have digits :
Digits 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 3

Step 1: Multiply the value of alternate digits by 2, starting
from the second rightmost digit.
example:
Digit       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  3
Multiplier X2    X2    X2    X2    X2

Step2: Add all the individual digits of the above products
together with the un-doubled digits from the original. If more 10 so add or subtract with 9.
number.

Example:

```
Digit       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  3
Multiplier X2    X2    X2    X2    X2
Result      2  2  6  4 10  6 14  8 18  3
                       1+0   1+4   1+8
Sum         2+ 2+ 6+ 4+ 1+ 6+ 5+ 8+ 9+ 3 = 40
```

Step 3: If the total modulo 10 is equal to 0, then the number is
valid according to the LUHN formula; otherwise it is
invalid.
example.
40 mod 10 = 0 so valid, if not 0 so not valid.

The question is, why in step 2 using Multiply by 2? what the reason? (with link refrence or papers please).
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although no explicit rationale for this detail is given in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), the multiplication of every second digit is likely to implement detection of typing errors in which adjacent places are exchanged. More precisely, it is mentioned that

> The Luhn algorithm will detect [...] almost all transpositions of adjacent digits. It will not, however, detect transposition of the two-digit sequence 09 to 90 (or vice versa).

If adjacent places are permutated, the checksum is likely to change. Without the different factors (2 for even positions from the right, 1 for odd positions) this would not be the case.